# Row vector problem

Tags: math-mode, vertical-alignment, vector

When I want to type a row vector, the design isn't good as it's showed in the figure. Normally the values inside the vector should be in the middle.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.gif,.jpg}
\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cclicenses}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
ccc
    $ \mathbf{X}= 
\begin{bmatrix}
\phi_{ds} & \phi_{qs} &  i_{dr} &  i_{qr}
\end{bmatrix}^t$\\
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem ... starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`. - Do you mean the middle in vertical direction?

Comment: Yes in the vertical direction as you can see they are not in the same line with =

Comment: The offset is really small, I think it seems so big because of the usage of `\phi`. Compare the following:     `$\begin{bmatrix} i \end{bmatrix} = i$`

Comment: the example code posted has lots of irrelevant packages, and does not produce the image shown

Answer (score 4):

The code posted in the question does not produce the output in the image shown so it is hard to be exact, but you can get more control over the brackets and ensure that the row vector is baseline aligned rather than vertically centred by using `array` directly.

[image]

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
ccc
    $ \mathbf{X}= 
\begin{bmatrix}
\phi_{ds} & \phi_{qs} &  i_{dr} &  i_{qr}
\end{bmatrix}^t$
%no!\\

\bigskip

ccc
    $ \mathbf{X}= 
[\begin{array}[t]{@{}cccc@{}}
\phi_{ds} & \phi_{qs} &  i_{dr} &  i_{qr}
\end{array}]^t$
%no!\\



\end{document}
```

or with `review` for more dramatic change

[image]

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
ccc
    $ \mathbf{X}= 
\begin{bmatrix}
\phi_{ds} & \phi_{qs} &  i_{dr} &  i_{qr}
\end{bmatrix}^t$
%no!\\

\bigskip

ccc
    $ \mathbf{X}= 
[\begin{array}[t]{@{}cccc@{}}
\phi_{ds} & \phi_{qs} &  i_{dr} &  i_{qr}
\end{array}]^t$
%no!\\



\end{document}
```

Comment: Add the `review` option and you'll see.

Comment: @egreg good grief what's the class up to:-) thanks I added an example with `review` back in.

Comment: @egreg oh I see: some wacky version of double spacing. Presumably to so divert the reviewer's attention that errors in the document are not picked up

Comment: This would do nothing for matrices with more than one row.

Comment: @egreg it would do nothing for world peace either, but the question was about row vectors so I gave an answer applicable to them:-)

Answer (score 1):

This is a by-product of the `review` option that does `\linespread{1.5}`.

Cure: precede every array by `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.6667}`

#### Example 1 (default output)

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{lipsum}% for context

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[3]
$ \mathbf{X}=
\begin{bmatrix}
\phi_{ds} & \phi_{qs} &  i_{dr} &  i_{qr}
\end{bmatrix}^t$
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Example 2 (with the cure)

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{lipsum}% for context

\ifpreprint % this is true for the review option
  \pretocmd{\array}{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.66667}}{}{}
\fi

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[3]
$ \mathbf{X}=
\begin{bmatrix}
\phi_{ds} & \phi_{qs} &  i_{dr} &  i_{qr}
\end{bmatrix}^t$
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]